# Confused on how to use arrays with an object with the calculation on another class.

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am making a program that finds the area of square. The calculation is done on another class. I have to use an array with values 1-10. I have to find the squares of those numbers in the array using the property from the other class. I am confused on how to do that. This is what I have done so far.

```
using System;
using Square;

namespace DemoSquares
{
    public class DemoSquares
    {
        static void Main()
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];

        Squares asquare = new Squares();

        asquare.Length = numbers[0]; 

        foreach (int i in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", i, asquare.Area);

        }
    }
}
```

}
This is the class.
    using System;

```
namespace Square
{
    class Squares
    {

    private int length;
    private int area;
    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return length;
        }
        set
        {
            length = value;
            CalcArea();
        }
    }      
    public int Area
    {
        get
        {
            return area;
        }
    }
    private void CalcArea()
    {
        area = Length * Length;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First populate the array with some values, possibly something like this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
int counter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
       numbers[i] = counter;
       counter++;
}
```

then you can find the area of each square like so:

```
foreach (int i in numbers)
{
     Squares asquare = new Squares();
     asquare.Length = i; 
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", i, asquare.Area);
}
```

**Another alternative**

```
int[] numbers = {
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  // enter your numbers here
};

numbers.ToList().ForEach(n => {
    Squares asquare = new Squares();
    asquare.Length = n;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", n, asquare.Area);
});
```

**note** - if you decide to go with the latter, ensure you import:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks but I just had to add this   Console.WriteLine("{0,6}", asquare.Area); in order to display the area

Comment: @VictorHughes sure go ahead and play around with the answer I've provided.

Answer (score -1):

I'am not shure if I understand you but this may work:

```
foreach (int i in numbers)
{
    asquare.Length = i;
    asquare.CalcArea();
    Console.WriteLine("Area for {0}: {1}", i, asquare.Area);
}
```

Comment: CalcArea() is private, you can replace the first two statements within your foreach loop with this--> Squares asquare = new Squares();
     asquare.Length = i;

Comment: Plus it is called when you assign the length so no need to call it again.